# How Can i get this Xpath

Tags: c#, selenium, cucumber, bdd

[image]

I got the id for capturing.

```
//button[contains(text(),'Delete')][1] 

//button[@id='deletebtn']
```

but its have 10 duplicate values.can't identify unique thing for capture the element.Please Help me to resolve

Comment: They must be in different `<td>` so use the `<td>` attributes

Comment: difficult to help you without html code...

Comment: Hi Frenchy I added Full HTML Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't shared full HTML I am assuming you want use the first locator of 10 matches.

You can use

```
//(button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[1]
```

instead of

```
//button[contains(text(),'Delete')][1]
```

In case, suppose you want to use an another element then change the match number. Like below,

```
//(button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[3]
```

or

```
//(button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[4]
```

**Note**: `Selenium` by default picks the first element if there are more than one match.

Always check your `xPath` in chrome console to make sure it is unique.

- Press `F12` in Chrome.
- Go to `elements` section
- Search ( `CTRL + F`)
- Place the `xpath` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node. This means, your `xPath` is unique.

Comment: I tried your mentioned code.it is correct but unfortunately its not working for my code. its only capturing [1] But  i want to capture 10th row. When i Give //(button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[10] its not working

Comment: What error you are getting? Have you tested the locators in chrome console?

Comment: Then use `//(button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[10]`

Comment: kendo.all.js:2178 Unknown DataSource transport type 'GET'. failed to load source map: Could not load content

Comment: I Used //(button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[10] but its not working .Above comment mentioned error caused.

Comment: Have you checked element in chrome console?

Comment: Yes Nandan. I have checked. I have Edit my HTML Code in the question(stackflow)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax to write the index based xpath.

Correct syntax for index based XPath-

```
(//button[contains(text(),'Delete')])[10]
```

PS: You can verify in SelectorsHub if your xpath is correct or not.